# Shortening code that provides a database description using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, workspace

I need advice on how to reduce the length of the sample code below. I need to perform the same work on several more datasets.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"\\gis\Env.gdb\Water"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='All')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
         path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        print(path)
############
arcpy.env.workspace = r"\\gis\Env.gdb\Soil"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='All')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
         path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        print(path)
###########
# need to repeat for several more datasets
```

I also have plans to take this further. I just wanted to clean up this segment as I go along. My goal is to create a text file that identifies, within a file or SDE database, all feature classes, their fields, and the data type and length of each field.

Comment: You could create a list using `workspaces = ["Water", "Soil"]` then use `for workspace in workspaces`, since everything after that point is repeated. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: @StephenLead I'll re-open so you can add that as an answer.  I did not notice that there was a particular aspect rather than multiple aspects for which help was being sought.

Comment: What is a "workspace" in this context?  To me they look like feature datasets, however you are looking for datasets inside those workspaces, and then printing the path for each.  I'm not sure this would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach which iterates through a list of workspaces, since it appears that you're performing the same operation on each workspace:

```
import arcpy, os

rootDir = "gis"
rootGDB = "Env.gdb"
workspaces = ['Water', "Soil"]

for workspace in workspaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(rootDir, rootGDB, workspace)

    datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='All')
    datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

    for ds in datasets:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
            path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
            print(path)
```

Comment: If you want to use this code that @Stephen Lead has created later in your code as well, consider putting this in a def function so it can be called at anytime during your script. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

The script below partly performs what I was aiming for. I am still working on having the result printed to a text file. Also, incorporating the advice provided by @Stephen Lead and @JamesLeversha may clean up the code.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env


arcpy.env.workspace = (r"P:\Training\Battle_Mountain\GDBFiles\Battle_Mountain.gdb\geology")

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='All')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
        fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
        for field in fields:
            print("Geology / "+ fc + "----"  + "{0}____{1}____{2}"
                 .format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`arcpy.da.Walk`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm). It encapsulates arcpy's ListWhatever functions in a version of Python's `os.walk` that can detect feature classes and datasets. You might also use nested dictionaries so you could write it to disk using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html). For example:

```
import os
import json
import arcpy

def make_gdb_dict(your_env):
    field_dict = {}
    # 'walk' through all directories/gdbs in a path
    for root, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(your_env):
        # iterate over the files in each directory/gdb
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, f)
            gdb_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))
            # filter out non-gis file types here
            if ".gdb" in path:
                fc_name = os.path.basename(path)
                # create a tuple of field info per feature class
                fields = [(field.name, field.type, field.length)
                          for field in arcpy.ListFields(path)]
                field_dict.update(
                    {gdb_name: {fc_name: {"path": path, "fields": fields}}})
    return field_dict

make_gdb_dict(r"C:\workspace")  # creates a dict such as:
"""
u'Countries.gdb':  # gdb #1 in your workspace
    u'USStates': {  # feature class #1 in gdb #1
        u'fields': [
            (u'OBJECTID', u'OID', 4),
            (u'Shape', u'Geometry', 0),
             ...]
        u'path': u'C:\\workspace\\Countries.gdb\\USStates'
        }
    u'Mexico':  # feature class #2 in gdb #1
        u'fields': [...],
        u'path': u'C:\\workspace\\Countries.gdb\\Mexico'
        ...}
}
u'Another.gdb':  # gdb #2 in your workspace...
"""

# write to disk as JSON
with open("json_dump.json", "w") as out_json:
    json.dump(make_gdb_dict(r"C:\workspace", out_json, indent=1)
```